# sql query that needs to be grouped and sent to json format mvc

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is the current method that I am trying to implement

```
 var emails = db.AuditAll.Where(m => m.UserName.Contains(search))
    .GroupBy(g => g.UserName)
    .Select(m => new 
    { 
        name = m.OrderBy(o => o.UserName), 
        value = "", 
        AdditionInfo = "" 
    })
    .ToList();

    return Json(emails, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

but when it is diplayed in the html it is only showing `[object Object]` but it must be an email address.

As soon as I take the `groupBy` out the results are provided correctly but it shows every username in the table that is called doen't matter how many times the same username has been provided.

I am trying to implement typeahead with the results that is sent back.

Comment: Would you mind if I reformatted your code to avoid all that sideways scrolling? I find that one LINQ call per line ends up being more readable in general, and *much* better for Stack Overflow with its narrow lines.

Comment: It's not at all clear how you're displaying this in HTML - but do you understand that the `name` property will be a *sequence* of results, not just a single result?

Comment: Is this really Sql?   Should it not have a `linq`tag ?

Comment: Yes i know that but for example there are 4 rows containing the same username and i only want to show that username once. But in reality I get that username shown to me 4 times.

Comment: So it sounds like you should have `name = m.Key` - or just use `.Select(m => m.UserName).Distinct()`. And why do you have that `value` and `AdditionInfo` with the same value for every item? You should really provide some more context here...

Comment: Thank you the `.Select(m => m.UserName).Distinct()` helped and fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GroupBy` in Linq returns `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` which is a collection of grouped elements by key. So if you just want to get distinct elements by `UserName`. You can try this code.

```
     var emails = db.AuditAll.Where(m => m.UserName.Contains(search))
     .GroupBy(g => g.UserName)
     .Select(grp => grp.First())
     .Select(m => new 
     { 
       name = m.UserName, 
       value = "", AdditionInfo = "" 
     })
     .ToList();
```

Hope it helps!!!